# Keras binary classification model is not learning anything. How to improve my model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, cnn, image-classification

<s>I am trying to train a **binary** image classifier on a an imbalanced dataset of images which are really small in dimensions(the largest dimension is 40*70). I am augmenting images by grayscale, rescaling and resizing to 48*48. My keras model is not learning at all. Can you suggest some technique using which I can improve the model or data?</s>
I figured out the problem. It was my data. Without knowingly I was doing single class classification while doing binary classification. Any advice what approach to be taken?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote few notes on your implementation:

- Classification on imbalanced data can be a problem. How imbalanced is your dataset? You can try to compensate by training your model by feeding **balanced mini batches** of data. You artificially build each batch so that classes are more or less equally represented, so that your classifier can learn from all of them.
- I would change the last layers. I suggest you to use **softmax** activation at the output layer, and a **crossentropy loss function** that is specific for this task. The number of output nodes must be equal to the number of classes.
- **Adam optimizer** is commonly referred to as the best algorithm for gradient descent.
- **MAE** is a metric for regression tasks, it doesn't work for classification. You can use `'accuracy'` instead.

Comment: It is a binary classifier. So, do I still use these suggestions?

Comment: In a binary classifier, you have 1 output node. And isn't sigmoid activation better for binary classification?

Comment: My experience tells me it works better with two output layers + softmax activation. Check [this implementation](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow2.0_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow2.0__00.01_basic_Classifier.ipynb)